# Self Join Exercise. Have I over-complicated it?

Tags: sql, oracle

This my 3rd question on the same exercise, but by no means a duplicate.  The two previous questions were posted on **StackOverflow** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100254/sql-query-for-time-intervals-syntax-errors) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123351/oracle-syntax-error-on-join-to-sub-query).

Now I'm posting my Oracle solution (below) that works. I wonder if the same could've been simpler and/or much more efficient. Not in terms of CTE or analytic expressions but with basic simple logic.

**Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE Readings (
  user_id varchar(10),
  reading_time int ,
  x decimal(10,2),
  y decimal(10,2)
);


INSERT ALL
    INTO Readings (user_id, reading_time, x, y) VALUES ('u1', 60, 345, 400)
    INTO Readings (user_id, reading_time, x, y) VALUES ('u1', 100, 560, 300)
    INTO Readings (user_id, reading_time, x, y) VALUES ('u2', 35, 1024, 250)
    INTO Readings (user_id, reading_time, x, y) VALUES ('u1', 90, 450, 450)
    INTO Readings (user_id, reading_time, x, y) VALUES ('u3', 150, 600, 100)
    INTO Readings (user_id, reading_time, x, y) VALUES ('u3', 100, 500, 125)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

**Intermediate script**:

```
SELECT r.user_id, rm.reading_time start_time, r.reading_time end_time, 
       (r.reading_time-rm.reading_time) time_spent,
       (TO_CHAR(rm.x)||' ; '||TO_CHAR(rm.y)) start_point, 
       (TO_CHAR(r.x)||' ; '||TO_CHAR(r.y)) end_point,
       SQRT(POWER(r.x-rm.x, 2)+POWER(r.x-rm.y, 2)) distance            
FROM Readings r 
JOIN Readings rm ON (r.user_id = rm.user_id and 
                     rm.reading_time = (SELECT MAX(r2.reading_time) FROM Readings r2 WHERE r2.reading_time < r.reading_time))
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

**Final script**:

```
SELECT rr.user_id, SUM(rr.distance) "Total Distance", 
       SUM(rr.time_spent) "Total Time", SUM(rr.distance)/SUM(rr.time_spent) "Average Speed" 
FROM 
(SELECT r.user_id, (r.reading_time-rm.reading_time) time_spent,
        SQRT(POWER(r.x-rm.x, 2)+POWER(r.x-rm.y, 2)) distance            
FROM Readings r 
JOIN Readings rm ON (r.user_id = rm.user_id and 
                     rm.reading_time = (SELECT MAX(r2.reading_time) FROM Readings r2 WHERE r2.reading_time < r.reading_time))) rr
GROUP BY rr.user_id
ORDER BY 1;
```

**Exercise Description**

Multiple *users* roam a plain and at irregular time intervals report their *coordinates* (x, y).  This information (user id, time-stamp and the coordinates) populate table `Readings`.

For each user that reported more than one set of coordinates we need to find *total distance traveled*, *total time spent*, and their *average speed*.

For the sake of simplicity coordinates are Cartesian and time-stamps are integers.

Comment: Always put your units.  Never reference columns numerically, always do it by name (this saves you from re-ordered columns in the select surprising you).  Recent versions of Oracle support additional analysis functions that might help you (like [LAG/LEAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#autoId18)) - see if any of those might help you.

Comment: what are you actually trying to compute? What is the problem statement of the exercise?

Comment: @abuzittin gillifirca - added to the post (at the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have a bug. Change the row `('u3', 100, 500, 125)` to `('u3', 99, 500, 125)`, and try again. You will see that `u3` row disappears.

  You can fix it with the following minimal change:

  ```
  rm.reading_time = (SELECT MAX(r2.reading_time) 
    FROM Readings r2 
    WHERE  r2.user_id=r.user_id -- you have to join on ids first
    and r2.reading_time < r.reading_time)
  ```
- There is another bug here:
  `r.x-rm.y` should have been `r.y-rm.y`.
- `user_id, reading_time` is a unique key by problem definition. Having it declared will enable us to detect some invalid inputs. What is the average speed of an object that can be at more than one place?
- I would go along with something like this for the intermediate script:

  ```
  SELECT t.*, t2.*
  FROM (SELECT r.user_id,r.reading_time, 
           max(r.x) AS x1, max(r.y) AS y1, 
           max(rm.reading_time) AS prev
  FROM Readings r
  JOIN Readings rm ON (r.user_id = rm.user_id AND rm.reading_time < r.reading_time)
  GROUP BY r.user_id,r.reading_time) t
  INNER JOIN Readings t2
  ON t.user_id = t2.user_id AND t2.reading_time = t.prev;
  ```